# Modifying a page by many users

Tags: web-services, http, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web

In a web application, when 5 users are connected to it, and there is a part of the page that users can modify (for example the vote counter in stackoverflow). If a user make a vote_up, when will the other user connecte detect that modification?

Does the server automatically refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer technology websocket and comet. That seems server push the data to client with a long-held HTTP connection.

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

[2]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: +1 - I have used Comet. Works like a charm. You can also refer the tutorial @ https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-cometjava/‎